# Convert static query from column to row results

Tags: mysql

I want convert a query that generated column results to row results.

I simplified production query with more 1000 columns and different numbers but same logic.

My example:
convert the following query:

SELECT 1,2,3

actual results:

```
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
-------------------
```

expected results:

```
-----------
|  title  |
-----------
|    1    |
-----------
|    2    |
-----------
|    3    |
-----------
```

Comment: Is this an over-simplification of the real issue I wonder

Comment: @Strawberry you are right because this query is built dynamically.

Comment: Perhaps we should start there. Otherwise, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot pattern:

```
SELECT 1 as `title`
UNION
SELECT 2 as `title`
UNION
SELECT 3 as `title`;
```

Comment: But if I have 100,000 entities, it wouldn't be realistic to make this query